# Добавить mouseleave() куда?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



 $("#switch")
  .button()
  .hover(function(){
        $("#panel").animate({left:'600px'});
  });

});
```

Куда добавить mouseleave() что бы панель вернулась на место?

Answer (score 1):

Передаёшь вторым аргументом в hover():

```
$("#switch")
  .button()
  .hover(
         function(){ $("#panel").animate({left:'600px'}); },
         function(){ // body of mouseleave function }
        );
});
```